# Change which variable is added to in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I'm struggling to understand how I change which variable is being added to in a function.

Essentially, when a user chooses a hotel, it needs to be added to hotelSelection. When they click next, it updates a map with restaurants, and when they choose restaurants, it needs to go into restaurantSelection. That's the bit I'm stuck on, changing it from hotel selection to restaurant selection.

Here's a snippet:

```
var hotelSelection = "";
var restaurantSelections = "";
var sightSelections = "";

function chooseSelection(resultIndex) {

    var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName-' + resultIndex);

    hotelSelection = `<div class="input-group" id="Hotel-chosen">
                                <li class="list-group-item"> 
                      <strong>${locationName.innerHTML}</strong><br>`;

    var locationRating = document.getElementById('locationRating-' + 
    resultIndex);

    hotelSelection += `rating: ${locationRating.innerHTML}</li>`

    console.log("Hotel Selection: " + hotelSelection);

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I think we need a bit more context.  How is this function called?  Where does `resultIndex` come from?

Comment: Your function is unfortunately rather specific. I'd guess that you'd be better of having an agnostic selected variable, along with an additional parameter of _type_ (being hotel, restaurant) etc and applying the function to each selection as demonstrated in second part of the answer below. _This comment assumes that the HTML is fundamentally different for each selection_

Answer (score 0):

This gets to the heart of how a function can communicate. What you are doing is accessing a variable in a higher "closure." This has its good and bad points, and one of the bad points which you're finding now is that it isn't very flexible.

If instead of doing it this way you were able to use the return value of the function, you would have the flexibility to do what you're saying. For example:

```
var hotelSelection = "";
var restaurantSelections = "";
var sightSelections = "";

function chooseSelection(resultIndex) {

    var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName-' + resultIndex);

    var selection = `<div class="input-group" id="Hotel-chosen">
                                <li class="list-group-item"> 
                      <strong>${locationName.innerHTML}</strong><br>`;

    var locationRating = document.getElementById('locationRating-' + 
    resultIndex);

    selection += `rating: ${locationRating.innerHTML}</li>`

    console.log("Hotel Selection: " + hotelSelection);
    return selection;
}
```

If you do this, then when you call the function you just assign the return value to a variable, like this:

```
hotelSelection = chooseSelection(someIndex);
sightSelections = chooseSelection(someIndex);
```